# Rules for Dazed in Arcadia Quest

Tags: arcadia-quest

What (and where) are the rules for Dazed heroes and monsters in basic  Arcadia Quest? I know I've read them, but I can't seem to find them hunting through the rule book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Arcadia Quest rulebook (accessed [here](http://arcadiaquest.com/AQ-Rulebook.pdf)), page 27:

> DAZE
> Some attacks are able to daze their target, leaving him open to
> future attacks. When a Character is dazed, lay its figure on its
> side to indicate his condition. A dazed Character is not allowed
> to roll any Defense dice against attacks. Other than that, he
> may act normally, moving and attacking as usual. When a dazed
> Hero Rests he recovers from the daze effect. Place his figure
> back up to indicate that.

Incidentally, the rulebook has an index on page 35, which lists where you can find the rules for Daze.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've no idea how I managed to completely ignore the index.